# `gopls` disagrees with `go test` on interface implementation

Tags: go, go-testing, go-interface, gopls

Consider the following code:

```
  package ifaces

  import (
          "fmt"
          "testing"
  )

  type IFace1 interface {
          Do1()
  }

  type IFace2 interface {
          Do2()
  }

  type Inner struct {
  }

  func (i *Inner) Do2() {
          fmt.Printf("Do2\n")
  }

  type Outer struct {
          Inner
  }

  func (o *Outer) Do1() {
          fmt.Printf("Do2\n")
  }

  func TestInterface(t *testing.T) {
          o := Outer{}
          var i interface{}
          i = o

          a := i.(IFace2)
          a.Do2()
  }
```

In summary, `Inner` implements `Iface2`, while `Outer` implements `Iface1` and embeds `Inner`.

Checking `Outer` via `gopls` (with `vim-go`'s command `GoImplements`) gives the following response:

```
  test/ifaces/interfaces_test.go|8 col 6| type IFace1 interface {                                                                                                                                                                             
  test/ifaces/interfaces_test.go|12 col 6| type IFace2 interface {
```

However, running the test results in the following error:

```
$ go test test/ifaces/interfaces_test.go 
--- FAIL: TestInterface (0.00s)
panic: interface conversion: ifaces.Outer is not ifaces.IFace2: missing method Do2 [recovered]
    panic: interface conversion: ifaces.Outer is not ifaces.IFace2: missing method Do2

goroutine 18 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1.2({0x5095c0, 0xc0000a23c0})
    /home/x/sdk/go1.19.3/src/testing/testing.go:1396 +0x24e
testing.tRunner.func1()
    /home/x/sdk/go1.19.3/src/testing/testing.go:1399 +0x39f
panic({0x5095c0, 0xc0000a23c0})
    /home/x/sdk/go1.19.3/src/runtime/panic.go:884 +0x212
command-line-arguments.TestInterface(0x0?)
    /home/x/D/git/personal/go/test/ifaces/interfaces_test.go:36 +0x27
testing.tRunner(0xc0000829c0, 0x52f520)
    /home/x/sdk/go1.19.3/src/testing/testing.go:1446 +0x10b
created by testing.(*T).Run
    /home/x/sdk/go1.19.3/src/testing/testing.go:1493 +0x35f
FAIL    command-line-arguments  0.004s
FAIL
```

As shown in the snippet, this is Go 1.19: why does the program panic, if `gopls` says the interface is implemented?

Does holding `Outer` inside an `interface{}` variable have anything to do with this error?  Note the error explicitly mentions `Outer` (`ifaces.Outer is not ifaces.IFace2`).

Running the same code against 1.13.15 produces the same panic, so this does not seem to be a bug (or it is a very old bug :)

Comment: Use `i = &o` in the test. Since it's `*Inner` that implements the interface you need `*Outer` instead of `Outer`. I'm not familiar with `gopls` nor vim-go `GoImplements` so I can only guess that the output from vim-go `GoImplements` shows the set of interfaces implemented by both `T` and `*T` _as a convenience_, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks, @mkopriva!  That definitely did the trick, but I can't say I understood it.  What you're saying is that when the `i` received `o`, it received the method set only `Outer` method set, not `*Outer`'s? And then, when the type assertion was run it only saw `Outer` method set, and concluded that it did not implement `IFace2`?  Can you help me with any keywords that would get me to some resource that explains that behavior?

Comment: The ONLY resource you need to understand the language proper is the official [language specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec). Regarding method sets you can take a look at the [method sets](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_sets) section of the spec. The first two points in that section are the most relevant ones for you question.

Comment: And these points in section https://go.dev/ref/spec#Struct_types: `If S contains an embedded field T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T. The method set of *S also includes promoted methods with receiver *T.`, `If S contains an embedded field *T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T or *T.`.

Comment: I want to add that `o.Do2()` is valid because `When the value is addressable, the language takes care of the common case of invoking a pointer method on a value by inserting the address operator automatically`. See https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#pointers_vs_values